# what is Derived Classes with Depth in C++?

Tags: c++, derived-class

I am reading some C++ text at the address https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~chris.szalwinski/archives/btp200.082/content/dclas.html. At the beginning, the author wrote:
"`A derived class with depth is a derived class that accesses resources through one or more of the derived class' instance variables.`"

I really dont get this definition, although I can understand the rest of the text. Can anyone give me a clear explanation or an example?

Comment: I never heard that term... and the rest of that text is also not of much quality too...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: typical C with classes :/

Comment: Google has very little to say about it. Looks like a term coined and used only in cs.senecac.on.ca...

Comment: Drop that book and pick a good one instead. C++ is already maze difficult enough without adding wrong maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *suppose* it refers to a chain of derived classes:

```
struct Base { int i; };
struct D0: Base {};
struct D1: D0 {};

int main() {
  D1 d;
  d.i; // access i through D0 through Base
}
```